# Array Maximum and Minimum number

Tags: c++

i was trying to write a code that get the max and min in array using classes and functions.

```
    #include "Header.h"

    int MaxMin::MaxArray(int Numbers[5])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Numbers[i];
            if (Numbers[i] > MaxNum)
                MaxNum = Numbers[i];
        }
        return MaxNum;
    }

    int MaxMin::MinArray(int Numbers[5])
       {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
     Numbers[i];
     if (Numbers[i] < MinNum)
        MinNum = Numbers[i];
    }
    return MinNum;
    }
```

and here is the main.cpp

```
    #include "Header.h"
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    void main()
    {
        MaxMin N;
        int Numb[5];
        int choice;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter the array Number " << i << " :";
            cin >> Numb[i];
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "Your max Number is : " << N.MaxArray(Numb) << endl;
        cout << "Your Min Number is : " << N.MinArray(Numb) << endl;

        system("Pause");
    }
```

the max number worked fine  , but the minimum number result was 0 !

Comment: [There already exists a function in the standard library to get the min and max values of a range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element). What's wrong with it?

Comment: As for how to solve your current code, I recommend you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line.

Comment: Also, what is `MinNum` and `MaxNum`? How are they initialized (I guess the problem have to do with initialization)? Where's the [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? And what do you think the statement `Numbers[i];` does?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude He said he was using classes and max was working so chances are `MinNum` and `MaxNum` are fields.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're not setting the default max/min before starting to search. That means it's going to start at 0 which assuming you have only positive numbers will probably work for max but will fail for min (opposite for negatives and fails for both positive and negatives).

There are 2 ways to solve this. 1 set the original value to the minimum (for max) or maximum (for min) allowable value or just set it to the first value.

so:

```
int MaxMin::MaxArray(int Numbers[5])
{
    MaxNum = Numbers[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (Numbers[i] > MaxNum)
            MaxNum = Numbers[i];
    }
    return MaxNum;
}

int MaxMin::MinArray(int Numbers[5])
{
   MinNum = Numbers[0];
   for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
   {
     if (Numbers[i] < MinNum)
         MinNum = Numbers[i];
   }
   return MinNum;
}
```